# Images in jQuery Nivo slider undesirably appear when they're loading

Tags: nivo-slider

I am reposting this from someone else who asked the same question.

So I'm working on a site where I've implemented the Nivo slider and the problem I have is that, when my page loads (fresh or after cached) is that the images all show up straight down the page and when the page fully loads, then the images disappear and the slide animations begin.

Check it out here: www.tigergolfandspatours.com/thailand2.html

the answer was given to add style="display:none" to all of the slides except the first one, but it's not working. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

no display:none wont do. You need to give the following property to the div containing slider (images). lets assume div has class slider that contain images.

```
    div.slider { overflow: hidden; }
```